# máximo hitNumber por visitID - google bigquery

Tags: sql, google-analytics-api, bigquery

Preciso coletar apenas o último hitnumber por visitID em uma consulta de uma base de dados do Google analytics via google big query. Abaixo segue meu código atual. Cheguei até o ponto de ordenar a consulta onde o hitnumber máximo aparece primeiro por visitId.

```
SELECT 
    visitNumber,
    visitId,
    date, 
    hitNumber,
    device.operatingSystem,
    device.operatingSystemVersion,
    device.mobileDeviceBranding,
    device.screenResolution,
    appInfo.exitScreenName,
    appInfo.screenName,
    eventInfo.eventCategory,
    eventInfo.eventAction,
    eventInfo.eventLabel,
  FROM `nomeConta.idConta.ga_sessions_yyyymmdd`  
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST (hits)
  WHERE appInfo.exitScreenName = "nomeTelaErro"
    and appInfo.screenName like "%identificacaoTela%"
    and date >= 'yyyymmdd'
  order by  visitID, hitNumber DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma window function para descobrir o maior hitNumber do usuário e depois filtrar só o hit que é igual a esse hitNumber. Seria algo assim:

```
with user_hits as (
    SELECT 
        visitNumber,
        visitId,
        date, 
        hitNumber,
        device.operatingSystem,
        device.operatingSystemVersion,
        device.mobileDeviceBranding,
        device.screenResolution,
        appInfo.exitScreenName,
        appInfo.screenName,
        eventInfo.eventCategory,
        eventInfo.eventAction,
        eventInfo.eventLabel,
        -- descobre o maior hitNumber por visitId, sem agregar a tabela
        MAX(hitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY visitId) as maxHitNumber
    FROM `nomeConta.idConta.ga_sessions_yyyymmdd`  
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST (hits)
    WHERE appInfo.exitScreenName = "nomeTelaErro"
    and appInfo.screenName like "%identificacaoTela%"
    and date >= 'yyyymmdd'
    order by  visitID, hitNumber DESC
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM user_hits
WHERE hitNumber = maxHitNumber
```

Você pode ver mais sobre window functions na documentação do BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts?hl=pt-br

Comment: Deu super certo, muito obrigada!